# How can I access variables in nested structures the same way as unnested variables in Julia?

Tags: julia, encapsulation

I am new to Julia, so I am sorry if this is an obvious or easy question. I tried googling it, but could not find a good solution.

In Julia, there is no inheritence. My solution to this is to have structures encapsulating structures. E.g.:

```
mutable struct A
    Var1::Int64
end

mutable struct B
    StructA::A
    Var2::Int64
end

MyA = A(1)
MyB = B(MyA, 2)
```

Now, when I want to get Var2, I just do:

```
MyB.Var2
>2
```

To get Var1, I can do:

```
MyB.StructA.Var1
>1
```

Or I can do:

```
Var1(x::B) = x.StructA.Var1
Var1(MyB)
>1
```

But now for my question, can I also (re)define a function such that I can do this?:

```
MyB.Var1
>1
```

I tried just typing the access to Var1, hoping that the function I defined above would automatically be extended to this use. But I got the expected error:

```
MyB.Var1
ERROR: type B has no field Var1
```

I also tried defining the function myself:

```
x::B.Var1 = x.StructA.Var1
ERROR: type DataType has no field Var1

(x::B).Var1 = x.StructA.Var1
ERROR: UndefVarError: x not defined
```

These errors do not surprise me. But I do not know how to get what I want, if it is at all possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible by extending `getproperty` for your type:

```
function Base.getproperty(b::B, s::Symbol)
    if s == :Var1
        return b.StructA.Var1
    else
        return getfield(b, s)
    end
end
```

Now you can just write:

```
julia> MyB.Var1
1
```

More info here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.getproperty

There is also a corresponding `setproperty!` function for modifying fields.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Appreciate the response.

Comment: Followup question: If I have many variables in StructA, is there a easier way to define getproperty than just reiterating if ... elseif ... elseif ... etc., or would that be the way to go?

Comment: Yes, you can use the `hasfield` function to determine whether the caller is asking for a built-in field, and if not, forward the call to the wrapped struct. Just take care to not cause an infinite loop.